# Removing rows based on how often they a value occurs

Tags: r

I am working with the Supreme Court Database, a very large data set. I am making new data frames for each natural court, but am only interested in cases in which all 9 justices have voted. Each justice's vote is a row in the data set where only the justice name and vote values are different. Is there a way to eliminate all case names that occur less than 9 times (ie. case names that occur in less than nine consecutive rows)?

Comment: `DF[ ave(seq(nrow(DF)), DF$Case, function(x) length(x)==9) ]` or similar.

Comment: Can you give sample dataset?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, if(uniqueN(justice)>8) .SD, by = court]
```